# Animations ruined after exporting?

Tags: animation, rigging, export

Here's one of the animation after exporting(For source engine SMD)
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9_rkNc6Ob7w
I have no idea what happened to the....I don't even know now
[image: This is what it looked like before]

Can somebody please help me?? Thanks